# Intersection between ray and sphere - solving a quadratic equation

Tags: java, eclipse, raytracing

I can't figure out how to solve my quadratic equation to check an intersection between the ray and sphere. The sphere should look like this:

[Final sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C5yS.jpg)

```
        // r = radius = sphere.radius;
        // m = center = sphere.center;

        float t;

        // ray intersection uses quadratic equation
        float a, b, c, d;

        // NOT SURE ABOUT THIS PART HERE !
        a = rayVx * rayVx + rayVy * rayVy + rayVz * rayVz;
        b = 2.0f * (rayEx * rayVx + rayEy * rayVy + rayEz * rayVz - rayVx * sphere.center[0] - rayVy * sphere.center[1] - rayVz * sphere.center[2]);
        c = rayEx * rayEx - 2 * rayEx * sphere.center[0] + sphere.center[0] * sphere.center[0] + rayEy * rayEy - 2 * rayEy * sphere.center[1] + sphere.center[1] * sphere.center[1] + rayEz * rayEz - 2 * rayEz * sphere.center[2] + sphere.center[2] * sphere.center[2] - sphere.radius * sphere.radius;

        // positive discriminant determines intersection
        //d = -42;
        d = (float) Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);
        // no intersection point? => next object
        if (d <= 0)
            continue;

        // from here: intersection takes place!

        }
    }

    // no intersection point found => return with no result
    if (minObjectsIndex == -1)
        return null;

    // intermediate version
    Random rd = new Random();
    return new Color(rd.nextFloat(), rd.nextFloat(), rd.nextFloat());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Raytracer00 rt = new Raytracer00();

    rt.doRayTrace();
    }
}
```

I am clueless at the moment. I don't really understand how to solve the quadratic equation for a,b,c.
 I uploaded the whole project on [workupload](https://workupload.com/file/SCYCzhXh37K) if someone want to see the complete project.

I am coming from the iOS world and never did something in Java before (sadly). 
I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the first thing you really want to do is restructure your code. Your geometry related to just one specific type of objects should not be in the top-level ray tracer implementation, it should neatly be encapsulated in a class. You can easily use interfaces to achieve polymorphism and not have to do `instanceof` checks like you're doing. In the meantime, you might want to remove all your code from this question except the lines related to just the geometry calculations you're struggling with

Comment: @Dici Ok, I deleted some lines of code. Thanks for your input